# What is the meaning of pre-doctoral program?

Tags: phd

I do not know the exact meaning of pre-doctoral? 
Can someone be a predoctoral in university X and then goes to university Y to start Ph.D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it is exactly will vary between institutions, but often includes things like:

Library use - services for researchers etc

Research methods - a reminder / review of research practices - some are coming back after a period away...

It could also include some courses that are relevant for some while not others ie advanced calculus if that is needed and the student did not take it in the studies they have done already.

So, it may or may not be identical, but the purpose is the same. Some institutions will have this as a prior requirement others run it in parallel during the first 6 months...

Answer (score 3):

In some parts of the world, this is the term used for a PhD program.

Before you obtain your doctorate (i.e. PhD), you are a pre-doctoral fellow or a doctoral candidate. After you have obtained it, you may become a post-doctoral fellow.

Example: http://www.ral.uni-leipzig.de/en/home/postdocs/pre-doc-award/

---

In other parts of the world, "predoctoral" may refer to the period before a student enrolls in a PhD programme.

---

On a related note, the term "PhD" is much abused these days with students who have not yet obtained a PhD being referred to as "PhDs". This is quite inaccurate as they have not yet obtained the degree and are thus not "doctors". They are a "PhD *students*", i.e. studying towards obtaining a doctorate.

Comment: Actually, in the U.S., in mathematics, it is quite popular current usage to say "start a Ph.D.".

Comment: @paulgarrett Fair enough, removed that bit.